# Construct a Regex matching a password

Tags: regex

How would you construct a regex matching a password that must consist of 6 to 16 characters and contain at least one number or special character?

Comment: Have you tried anything till now?

Comment: You shouldn't limit a password, you have to hash it anyways.

Comment: All passwords should be 8 (or more)-infinity characters :)  They should be reduced to [block size of your cryptographic hash] anyway (with salting), so a fixed-width database column is no reason to limit their length.

Comment: This sounds like someone trying to get SO to do their HW to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define what constitutes special characters for you.

Something like this regex should work:

```
(?=^.*?[\d#;:'"()`~@!%$&=-])^.{6,16}$
```

Comment: linebreak naturally :) and he has asked how you would do that so I think it belongs into your answer, not as a question back ;) (just joking)

Comment: That's a really ingenious use of a look-ahead. I had to think for a moment: "Oh, yeah, look-aheads are zero-length, so ^ still matches."